# Parsley.js: How can I pass a function as data attribute?

Tags: parsley.js

The [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/) says:

> It is also possible to configure it with a callback function from javascript

How? I am getting the error: "t.options.classHandler is not a function"

```js
function test_function(field) {
 return $('.outer'); 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div>
<input type="text" data-parsley-class-handler="test_function" required />
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify it using javascript:

```
$('.your-input').parsley().options.classHandler = function(field) { ... }
```

If all you want is return `$('.outer')`, you can directly set the parameter to '.outer', though.

It would be nice to support global functions though as in your example.

Comment: Do I need to specify it on form:init, after the parsley init or whenever? I think it would be good to have a example in the doc folder for this, because I also can't find an API documenation for the ParsleyField class (how to I access the current element).

Comment: Ok part of the problem was that I didn't use the most up to date parsley.js. So it appears that this can be set whenever after the parsley.js init as the function is executed for each validation.